# ConstraintLayout not showing last child

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I've defined a `ConstraintLayout` which consists of 3 parts

- a chart
- a block containing informations relative to the chart
- a refresh rate

defined as follow:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/graph_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/chartBackgroundColor"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="5:4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/chartBackgroundColor" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/information"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F21F2124"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/graph_frame">

        <!-- title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Current Volt. (3s)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average_voltage_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Average Volt."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_voltage_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/range_min_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Range min. (3s)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/average_voltage_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/range_max_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Range max. (3s)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_min_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/auto_focus_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Auto Focus"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_max_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lecture_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="Lecture"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auto_focus_title" />

        <!-- value -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_voltage_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.currentVoltageLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average_voltage_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.averageVoltageLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_voltage_value" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/range_min_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.rangeMinVoltageLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/average_voltage_value" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/range_max_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.rangeMaxVoltageLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_min_value" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/auto_focus_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.autoFocusLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_max_value" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lecture_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.autoPlayLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auto_focus_value" />

        <!-- pause -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pause_button"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.pauseButtonPressed()}"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/auto_focus_button"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

        <!-- auto-focus -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/auto_focus_button"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.autoFocusButtonPressed()}"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pause_button" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warning"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#CC1F2124"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{viewModel.refreshRateLabelValue}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/information"
        tools:text="Refresh rate = 125ms" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.imihydronic.hytune.features.oscilloscope.OscilloscopeViewModel" />
</data>
```

Everything is showing as expected in the preview from Android Studio:
[image: Android Studio preview]

But unfortunately the last block (the refresh rate one) does not appear on a real device:
[image: Real device preview]

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
The layout given above was used for a `Fragment`. This `Fragment` was inflated inside a `FrameLayout` container which in turns was wrapped by a `ScrollView`. Removing the `ScrollView` and using Taslim Oseni solution did the work.

Comment: Here your chart view may be taking more than expected height. So the text view is not showing. You can set a constraint for all view from the bottom parent also instead of top.

Comment: @KoushikMondal If I do the reverse (constraining views from bottom to top), it's the chart that isn't showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you have three views lined up linearly with id: *graph_frame*, *information* and *warning*. **A quick fix would be to constrain each of these three views at both vertical ends** (top and bottom). This way all three views would always fit the screen no matter what.

Therefore your code would look this way (I truncated the code to improve readability):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/graph_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/chartBackgroundColor"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="5:4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/information">
    ...
</FrameLayout>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/information"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#F21F2124"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/graph_frame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/warning">
    ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/warning"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#CC1F2124"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@{viewModel.refreshRateLabelValue}"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/information"
    tools:text="Refresh rate = 125ms" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: The view is now scrolling i.e. everything does not fit on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Edit: Change all heights to 0dp, the double constraints already cater for the height. Check the updated code for insights.

Answer (score 0):

Use guidelines and constraint children between them.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `GuideLine` Constraint to get this.
>
> I added two horizontal guideline to divide screen in three section.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/graph_frame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/chartBackgroundColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/graph"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/chartBackgroundColor" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/information"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#F21F2124"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

            <!-- title -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Current Volt. (3s)"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/average_voltage_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Average Volt."
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_voltage_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/range_min_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Range min. (3s)"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/average_voltage_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/range_max_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Range max. (3s)"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_min_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/auto_focus_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Auto Focus"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_max_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lecture_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:text="Lecture"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auto_focus_title" />

            <!-- value -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_voltage_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{viewModel.currentVoltageLabelValue}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/current_voltage_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/average_voltage_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{viewModel.averageVoltageLabelValue}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/current_voltage_value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/range_min_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{viewModel.rangeMinVoltageLabelValue}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/average_voltage_value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/range_max_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{viewModel.rangeMaxVoltageLabelValue}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_min_value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/auto_focus_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{viewModel.autoFocusLabelValue}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/range_max_value" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lecture_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{viewModel.autoPlayLabelValue}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/current_voltage_value"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auto_focus_value" />

            <!-- pause -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pause_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.pauseButtonPressed()}"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/auto_focus_button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

            <!-- auto-focus -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/auto_focus_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.autoFocusButtonPressed()}"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pause_button" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/warning"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#CC1F2124"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{viewModel.refreshRateLabelValue}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline1"
            tools:text="Refresh rate = 125ms" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Nothing is appearing at all with your solution.

Comment: send screen shots .

Comment: Do you really want a screenshot of a white screen?

Comment: A SS which I post is from your layout only.

Comment: As stated in my question, the layout preview show the intended result... The on device result does not show the same thing though.